# Using all() function in pandas dataframe slice for filtering

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataframe, e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'one' : pd.Series(
            [1., 2., 3., 4.],
            index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        ),
        'two' : pd.Series(
            ['5,6', '7,8', '1,10', '3,8,9'], 
            index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        )
    }
)
```

[image: example_dataframe]

How can I select only rows in which column 2 does not contain any integer less than 3? My go at it was this:

```
df[
    all([int(x) > 3 for x in df['two'].str.split(',')])
]
```

But it throws

```
KeyError: True
```

at me. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is a list of strings, you need to add an inner loop to go through `x` and check the values:

```
df[
    [all(int(x) > 3 for x in s) for s in df['two'].str.split(',')]
]

#   one two
#a  1.0 5,6
#b  2.0 7,8
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `apply` method to replace the outer for loop:

```
df[
    df.two.str.split(',').apply(lambda s: all(int(x) > 3 for x in s))
]

#   one two
#a  1.0 5,6
#b  2.0 7,8
```

Comment: Why does my method not work? I mean logically. I think it just returns a `True` or `False` without an index and that's why. Because if you evaluate it for the first row for example `all([int(x) > 3 for x in ['5','6']])` == `all([True, True])` == `True`. Am I mistaken?

Comment: When you do `for x in df.two.str.split(',')` actually x is `['5', '6']` so you are doing `int(['5','6']) > 3` which won't work because you can't convert a list to int. Notice `df.two.str.split(',')` is actually a sequence of sequence (or list of lists).

Comment: I see, it's because `df.two.str.split(',')` actually returns a series, whose values are an array of an array. Thanks